# Display GeoJSON attribute on QGIS3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a GeoJSON file which represents geographical polygons.
Drag and drop to QGIS3 opens the file and I can see the polygons.

Each polygon has several properties identified by QGIS (Can see them via Layer Properties-> Fields)

Is there a way to display these fields (I only need one) on the map?

Comment: I'd like to solve: "What is a label?"

Answer (score 1):

To Elaborate on Eriks comment: what you want is called a label.

Labelling is explained in the manual here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#labels-properties .

You can label using fields in the source data or based on arbitrary complex expressions.